# 3.13.0-30 kernel issue will not log in / sign in

Tags: boot, upgrade, kernel

I did a recent update with the new kernel 3.13.0-30 seemed fine to start with booted to the desktop but after sign in just hung with only mouse inputs seeming to work and nothing else no menu our header bar.

I can boot ok with 3.13.0-29 and use the laptop but other than I'm pretty stuffed with the recent kernel any ideas?

specs:

- laptop: satellite C660D
- Processor: AMD E-450 APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics × 2
- graphics: VESA: WRESTLER

Answer (score 0):

There's a pretty old post about having just the background and mouse, and supposedly some fixes for it.  This did happen to me once, and I ended up reinstalling my system.

The basics: From the TTY window <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f1</kbd>, enter the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
export DISPLAY=:0
ccsm
```

Then re-enable graphics <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f7</kbd>, find an enable the unity plugin.

Or, again at the tty window

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/ 
unity --reset-icons &disown
```

There are other suggestions...  but as I said, I ended up doing a reinstall.  This was well before the 3.13.0.30 kernal, and I had been messing about with CompizConfig manager.

[Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)